# Swift Document Picker Directory URL

Tags: swift, swift5, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I implemented the UI Document Picker to select files from iCloud Drive, local storage etc. and it all works fine so far.
As we all know it is possible to also select files from apps like Dropbox, OneDrive etc. but for a user who does not know this is possible, the document picker can be quite confusing.

**Is it possible to implement a button to directly open the Dropbox Folder (or any other), instead of having to navigate trough the document directorys?**

Apple provides a functionality like directoryURL but im not sure if this works, especially if a user might not have installed an app like Dropbox or so.
I don't want to navigate to another app or use frameworks for this. I just want to programmatically change the starting point when opening the Document Picker to show files of external apps. It would be nice if it is also possible to check if an app is available/installed so that a button can be shown or not depending on that.

[Picture: Storages of external apps accessible with document picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3nrr.png)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift

Comment: @LeoDabus not what I was looking for... I don't want a special Framework for Dropbox or so but a way to directly open specific containers in the document picker

Comment: You can't set the initial location of the document picker AFAIK

Comment: @LeoDabus 
I suppose it's possible with this here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3183918-directoryurl
But how do I use it with DropBox, OneDrive, Google Drive etc ?

Comment: iOS13 and later only. Anyway you probably can not set the default value to a directory out of your app bundle. Every app is sandboxed so every time you run your app it will be a different location.